Angular HttpClient subscription returning undefined in async/await function
I have a service that uses API:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from '../../../enviroments/environment.development';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class LandingPageService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.updateTemperaturesForCities();
  }
  private regionSubject: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>(
    '',
  );
  openWeatherMapAPIKey = environment.APPID;
  responseData$: Observable<any> | undefined;
  async getDataForASpecifiedCity(city: string) {
    try {
      const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${this.openWeatherMapAPIKey}`;
      this.http.get(url).subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.responseData$ = data;
        const mainTemp = this.kelvinToCelsius(data.main.temp);
        const cityName = data.name;
        console.log(mainTemp);
        return mainTemp;
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  mainCities: any[] = [
    {
      city: 'Puerto rico',
      temperature: 25,
      desc: 'Take sunglasses and use SPF cream.',
      url: '../../../../../assets/weather/sunny.jpg',
    },
    {
      city: 'Warsaw',
      temperature: 10,
      desc: 'First days of spring are comming.',
      url: '../../../../../assets/weather/autumnly.jpg',
    },
    {
      city: 'Yakutsk',
      temperature: -10,
      desc: 'Wear a thick jacket and gloves.',
      url: '../../../../../assets/weather/snowy.jpg',
    },
  ];

  async updateTemperaturesForCities() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.mainCities.length; i++) {
      const cityName = this.mainCities[i].city;
      console.log('city is ', cityName);
      const temperature = await this.getDataForASpecifiedCity(cityName);
      console.log('temperature is' + temperature);
      this.mainCities[i].temperature = temperature;
    }
  }

  getCards() {
    return this.mainCities;
  }

  kelvinToCelsius(kelvin: number): number {
    const celsius = kelvin - 273.15;
    return Math.round(celsius);
  }
}

i want to get and display the weather for Warsawa, Puerto rico and Yaktusk. The console are correct, i get the data, but it doestn get displayed on the screen.
 try {
      const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${this.openWeatherMapAPIKey}`;
      this.http.get(url).subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.responseData$ = data;
        const mainTemp = this.kelvinToCelsius(data.main.temp);
        const cityName = data.name;
        console.log(mainTemp);
        return mainTemp;
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }

this function returns the correct values but
async updateTemperaturesForCities() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.mainCities.length; i++) {
      const cityName = this.mainCities[i].city;
      console.log('city is ', cityName);
      const temperature = await this.getDataForASpecifiedCity(cityName);
      console.log('temperature is' + temperature);
      this.mainCities[i].temperature = temperature;
    }
  }

and this
 console.log('temperature is' + temperature);

return undefined. Why? How to fix it? I thnik it is something with RxJS, but i call the async function with await so i thought it would work.

Your return mainTemp; inside .subscribe() ain't going nowhere. It's not like subscriptions work... You can think about it like 'last stop' of an observable.

It's undefined, because observable within async method is also async, so it doesn't return, so the method doesn't really return anything, which is why the return value is undefined.
You should probably refactor the code as to not mix observables and promises.
You could use firstValueFrom or lastValueFrom, but that would need some refactoring.
A quick and dirty fix would be to return a promise, and then resolve from observable callback:
  getDataForASpecifiedCity(city: string) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    
      this.http.get(url).subscribe((data: any) => {
        
        //...process...
        
        // now resolve
        resolve(mainTemp);
      });  

    });
  } 

Also, instead of try/catch, handle errors from observable like so:
return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {

  this.http.get(url).subscribe({
      next: (data: any) => {
      
      //...process...
      
      // now resolve
      resolve(mainTemp);
    },
    // error
    error: (err)=>{console.log(err);reject(err)}
   })
 }); 

     

or use operators, like so:
HTTP client - Handle request errors
see also:
Subscribe Arguments
